How can I get rid of the relationship printout?
I have a relationship where I am segmenting by language and outputting to the user with postman. But a relationship that I don't want also comes with it. I tried to remove it with unset but it didn't work, I'm just trying to filter by language.
If you suggest another method, I can try that too
my db
{"en":"English Machine Name","tr":"Türkçe Makine Adı"} 
public function all(Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->header('Accept-Language', App::getLocale());
        $searchValue = $request->input('search_value');

        $favoriteAll = Favorite::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->when($searchValue, function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->with(['favoriMachine' => function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%')
                        ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
                }]);
            })
            ->get();

        $result = $favoriteAll->map(function ($favorite) use ($locale) {
            if ($favorite->favoriMachine) {
                $favorite->favoriMachine = $favorite->favoriMachine->map(function ($machine) use ($locale) {
                    return [
                        'id' => $machine->id,
                        'name' => $machine->name[$locale] ?? $machine->name['en'] ?? $machine->name,
                        'description' => $machine->description[$locale] ?? $machine->description['en'] ?? $machine->description,
                        'images' => $machine->images,
                        'location' => $machine->location,
                        'address' => $machine->address,
                        'lat' => $machine->lat,
                        'lng' => $machine->lng,
                        'dealer_id' => $machine->dealer_id,
                        'is_active' => $machine->is_active,
                        'type' => $machine->type
                    ];
                });
            }
            return $favorite;
        });

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'Success',
            'data' => $result
        ]);
    }



I tried deleting it with unset, I tried uninstalling it with return, but it didn't work at all.

show your Favorite model and it's relationships


To hide relationships, add the relationship's method name to your Eloquent model's $hidden property.

class Favorite extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['favori_machine'];
}

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

if you want to hide 'favoriMachine' table data but you want to check some condition  use 'whereHas'
source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence
 $favoriteAll = Favorite::where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->when($searchValue, function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
            $query->whereHas('favoriMachine' => function ($query) use ($searchValue) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%')
                    ->orWhere('address', 'like', '%' . $searchValue . '%');
            });
        })
        ->get();

